# How to get address of variable in a VxWorks Project

Tags: vxworks

VxWorks how to get address of local variable to see the memory contents.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.
In the code, like mouviciel mentioned, simply use the address of operator (&):

> printf("var addr = %x", &var);

---

If you are in a vxworks host or target shell:

you can see global variables and static variables by simply entering the variable name.

> -> var
>      var = 0x103b4188: value = 10 = 0xa
>   ->

This gives you the address of the variable and the content.
However, this would not work with a local (automatic) variable, as it is on the stack.
The shell doesn't have a neat way of saying "show me the stack variable for Task X".

Comment: I didn't think of host or target shell. I consider your answer better than mine.

Comment: Locals don't have to be on the stack - they can also be in registers.      You need to look at the decompiled code and figure out where it's storing the variable.  If it's on the stack, you can still see it, just look at the appropriate memory location.

Comment: In code, you can absolutely see stack vars by using the address of operator. You still can't see automatic variables from the *vxworks shell*, which is what the last sentence refers to.

Answer (score 1):

This is like any other C environment: address of (local or global) `var` is `&var`.